# Is making the whole object constant same as making the whole object and the internal objects constant?

Tags: c++, constants

In a nutshell, the question is if the following 2 statements are equivalent:

```
const std::vector<std::vector<int>>
```

and

```
const std::vector<const std::vector<int>>
```

Because, out of the following 2 codes, the first one does not compile!

[code1](https://godbolt.org/z/GzdE7r)

```
#include <vector>

long findMaxSum(const std::vector<const std::vector<int>>& vecs) {

}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> stacks(10,std::vector<int>(10)); //yeah yeah I know stacks is evil!
    for (auto& stack : stacks) {
        for (auto& elem : stack) {
            elem = 4;
        }
    }
    auto t = findMaxSum(stacks);
    return 0;
}
```

[code2](https://godbolt.org/z/exYfYr)

```
#include <vector>

long findMaxSum(const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& vecs) {

}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> stacks(10,std::vector<int>(10));
    for (auto& stack : stacks) {
        for (auto& elem : stack) {
            elem = 4;
        }
    }
    auto t = findMaxSum(stacks);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're not quite the same, but there's really not a whole lot you can do about it.

As you've found, attempting to create a `vector` with elements that are `const` will generally fail.

You could make the outer collection an `std::array`--it doesn't place as tight of requirements on the elements it contains, so an `std::array<const std::vector<whatever>, SIZE>` is perfectly fine.

Another possibility would be to pass a vector of pointers to const vectors:

```
// receive a vector of pointers to const vectors:
int findMaxSum(std::vector<const std::vector<int> *> &outer) {
    std::vector<int> sums;
    std::transform(outer.begin(), outer.end(), 
        std::back_inserter(sums), 
        [](auto v) { return std::accumulate(v->begin(), v->end(), 0); });

    return *std::max_element(sums.begin(), sums.end());
}

int main() { 
    const std::vector<int> a {1, 2};
    const std::vector<int> b {3, 4};

    // pass only the address of each of the component vectors:
    std::vector<const std::vector<int> *> c { &a, &b};
    std::cout << findMaxSum(c) << "\n";
}
```

This has the added advantage of avoiding making a copy of each component vector just to pass it to the function. If the component vectors are large, this can be a substantial consideration.